# Onde ficam os dados, após uma solicitação para o servidor?

Tags: memória, navegador-de-internet, lado-do-cliente

Se eu clicar em um *link*, o navegador faz uma solicitação para o servidor, aí o servidor começa a baixar os arquivos (como imagens, vídeos, textos e etc.), onde ficam esses dados, na memória do computador ou do navegador? Tem como eu acessar esses dados ou não (sem necessariamente usar o navegador)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde fica exatamente é detalhe de implementação do navegador.

Certamente fica na memória do computador, porque só o computador tem memória, o navegador usa a memória do computador.

Inclusive pode ser memória primária ou principal, geralmente, até a presente data, que não tem persistência, então ela é apagada facilmente sem energia, ou pode ficar em memória secundária ou de massa, que tem persistência, e hoje costuma ser um HDD ou SSD.

Para a apresentação da tela do computador certamente o navegador carrega esse conteúdo na memória principal, caso contrário não teria como ele fazer a manipulação necessária, a memória de persistência não consegue oferecer isso diretamente.

A maneira de fazer isso está programada no software do navegador.

Embora seja possível acessar isso na memória principal, não vale o esforço, porque é trabalhoso demais.

Para acessar na memória secundária pode sim se você tem acesso ao equipamento. Não pode remotamente, a não ser por um *bug* extremamente grave. Os navegadores costumam deixar todo esse conteúdo em uma área de cache para acessar mais facilmente em outros acessos e não precisar trafegar de novo se você for acessar a mesma coisa.

Fica tudo lá, HTML, JS, CSS, imagens, vídeos, etc. Tudo o que é arquivo fica lá. Tem como evitar isso sob certas circunstâncias. Nem tudo o que você recebe é um arquivo. Ou seja, se alguém quiser limitar o seu acesso aos dados em um site, é possível fazer. Não quer dizer que a informação que você recebe não fique disponível para cópia de qualquer forma. Um *streaming* por exemplo pode não ficar armazenado, mas todos os *frames* do vídeo está sendo recebido, então de uma forma ou de outra você pode copiar, no caso mais extremo filmando com um dispositivo externo, mas dá para interceptar no próprio computador, sempre se tiver acesso total a ele.

O próprio navegador tem algumas ferramentas que ajudam ver esses arquivos.

Fui ver e aqui no meu fica em `C:\Users\<meu user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cache\Cache_Data`. Obviamente pode mudar de acordo com o navegador e sua versão.